# cannot display image in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Im trying to build a simply app to show an image in a stack layout,
here's the code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HelloWorld.Page1">
  <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
    <Image Source="http://placehold.it/300x300"/>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

but for some reason its not displaying the image at all.
Can any of you see something wrong here.

Thanks!!

Comment: when I paste that url in my browser I am getting redirected to https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300×300&w=300&h=300.  Try using that instead.  It's unlikely the image handler will follow a redirect.

Comment: i tried adding this link http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/nature/3/ but still it doesn't work

Comment: Make sure you have updated the Xamarin.Forms nuget package in your projects.  I just took that exact code and it worked.  I tested on Windows UWP and iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you don't have a well formed page?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QuickTestXAMLImage"
             x:Class="QuickTestXAMLImage.MainPage">

  <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
    <Image Source="http://placehold.it/300x300"/>
  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Notice that I have a xmlns:local which include the local namespace of the app.  It is possible you don't have a fully formed page that results in it not even loading correctly.

This works for me just fine.

Comment: well that's me just trying different stuff, while i was trying to include a local image. everything else works for me in xamarin except images for some reason.